# Unity sudden FPS drop

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I am developing a simple 3D mobile game using Unity. I am targeting 30 FPS without vsync. My game runs good on all iOS devices without heating and throttling but there are weird FPS drops. Suddenly FPS drops to 20 and after several seconds it is 30 again. This strange thing occurs every 10-20 seconds and it’s absolutely weird because my profiler shows smooth rendering stats. Can anyone help me?

Comment: you should post some screenshots of the profiler while this issue is happening, GPU and CPU

Comment: The profiler should show any drop. Could you post a screenshot as Empty mentioned

Comment: Could be the garbage collection depending how you game runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a short research I found a solution! This FPS drop occurs when GPU renders on full screen resolution. So I decreased my phone's screen resolution.

```
void Awake() {
    var resolution = Screen.currentResolution;
    var height = (int)(resolution.height * 0.65f);
    var width = (int)(resolution.width * 0.65f); 
    Screen.SetResolution(height, width, true);
}
```

Now my game works perfect on all iOS and Android devices without throttling and heating even after long sessions.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to remember a similar issue when unity was using it's auto blending feature. Try turning that off and see if you notice a difference